# In Gnomoria is there generally an advantage to walls and doors?

Tags: gnomoria

I tend to mine the heck out of the first few underground levels and use the areas to build workshops.  I usually mine them into one huge area--I'll just place a workshop that creates something next to a store and place that next to the workshop that consumes it with no walls in sight.

When I see other peoples maps they often build walls to enclose the workshops.

Is there an advantage to this (aside from aesthetic?)

Comment: In dwarf fortress there are strange moods, i don`t know if Gnomoria have something similar.

Comment: Not at the moment. And i don't remember anything  being planned about social interactions, but who knows? Maybe later, we can only hope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no advantage when it comes to workshops. For personal quarters however, walls count when calculating the value of the room. So you can use one wall to increase the value of two adjacent rooms. [Source](http://forums.gnomoria.com/index.php?topic=1734.msg12494#msg12494).

Comment: I would agree that asthetics are the major driver, and eventually adding Overall Value from construction to your kingdom.  Doors are useful in another way, in a less boxed in area plan, they slow the raiding of your stuff down.  Stone doors for example take a while to break so you can rally and launch a counter-attack against the aggressing foe(s).  So in a little "village" style area with individual enclosed shops, doors will help protect your gnomes and stuff.